# Separate different filetypes of movies to different folders on my NAS

Tags: video, nas, video-conversion, synology, file-organization

Background: I have more than 500 movies on my NAS. My Family could watch those movies wherever they are.
The main problem is my Synology DS215J NAS device can not play *.avi files, but can play mkv, wmv, mp4 , etc..

Current view:
[image]

My question is what would be the best method to organise these files to let my family easily find those files they can watch directly from NAS.

My first idea was to make 3-4 folders named by like #AVI #MP4 #MKV (hashtag is to make these folders TOP when they check the NAS with "view by name") and put the movies inside those folders. But i think it would be a problem if they would like to find an exact movie and they will not know which folder to look.

Second idea is to convert all the avi files to mkv or mp4, but it will take a really long time.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have telnet or SSH Access to your nas?

Comment: You could also consider transcoding the incompatible files to a more suitable format

Comment: @Mark I think i can make it (i bought the NAS last week, i am pretty new with it) For what reason should i use SSH for this problem?
yes, i tought i convert all the avi-s to mkv or mp4, but it will take long time to separate the files, convert them and reupload them...

Comment: Do you know what model of NAS you have?

Comment: Synology DS215J as it was mentioned. By the way ssh is working

Answer (score 0):

Bash (which should be accessible via SSH) provides filename matching using `glob` matching. This may be useful if all the files have names you want to match in the current directory. You could move all files with the name containing the string *mkv* to the directory *mkv_files* like this:

`mv *.mkv mkv_files/`

This would move all your files with an mkv extension *within the current directory* to a subdirectory called *mkv_files*

It looks like, from your photo, that you have files placed in subdirectories, therefore the above suggestion will not work for you.  You may find the following more useful (although more complex):

**1. Find all files matching a specific filename deep to your current directory**

First of all, be careful that you understand what you are about to do before running any commands which may potentially overwrite your data.

A good way of doing this is to print all the matches to the command line:

```
IFS=$'\n'; for i in $(find ./ -iname '*.mkv'); do echo "${i}"; done
```

What does this do?

first, `IFS=$'\n'` sets the *internal field separator* as the newline character which means each newline from the output of the find command will be treated as a separate entry, making it possible to process files with spaces in the filename.

`find ./ -iname '*.mkv'` runs a case-insensitive find for all files with a name ending in *.mkv* deep to the current directory

the `for i in` is a loop, that runs the code `echo ...` on each result in the find loop

**2. Now that you know the files you are about to operate on, run a command on each one:**

To move each of these files, you could run the `mv` command on each of these files.

First, create a directory to put all the matching results in:

```
# create a directory called mkv_files
mkdir mkv_files
```

Now, you can use the above command as a starting point:

```
IFS=$'\n'; for i in $(find ./ -iname '*.mkv'); do mv "${i}" mkv_files; done
```

Bear in mind that this may overwrite two MKV files if they have the same name. You can use the `-n` / `--no-clobber` option to tell `mv` not to overwrite files:

```
IFS=$'\n' for i in $(find ./ -iname '*.mkv'); do mv -n "${i}" mkv_files; done
```

Alternatively, you could adjust the above command to run the [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) command on each of your files, to convert them to your chosen codec.

Another example -- to move all directories containing a .mkv file to a separate directory called *mkv_directory*:

```
IFS=$'\n'; for i in $(find ./ -iname '*.mkv'); do mv $(dirname $i) mkv_directory/; done
```

Comment: Dear @Mark , 

Wow, thank you for your answer... Unfortunately i have to say i am pretty new to do any bash scripts. I understand what you write or try to explain to me,
When i connect to my NAS via SSH, i go to my movies folder, and i try to run your script but i only got error messages. With the " find ./ -iname '*.mkv'" i got the list of the mkv files. Please see picture below:
https://imgur.com/dTGFZk0

Comment: @Gabor what command would you like to run on each of the MKVs that you find? Are you thinking you would like to move them or transcode them? If you want to move them, where to - have you created a directory to move them? If you want to transcode them, decide on the command you would like to use for the transcoding - you'll need to think about the audio/video codecs, container format and compression ratio that you want to use. This will depend on the amount of processing power you have available to you

Comment: Well done for getting started with SSH

Comment: Try the `for` command again, I missed out a `;`